# Prove that $\cos x$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Is it enough, that by Heine Theorem, if  $f(x)=\cos x$ is continuous on $x\in [0,2\pi]$, then it’s uniformly continuous on $x\in [0,2\pi]$. But $f(x)$ is periodic by $2\pi$, so it’s uniformly continuous on $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: That's the right idea, but your last sentence could use some justification.

Comment: could use some justification - maybe, but absolutely right, why not?

Comment: What did I miss? Can you please write down the missing part for me?

Comment: This is my question as well. Let f be _any_ periodic continuous function. Any idea how to find a one that is not uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $\cos x$ with respect to $x$ is $-\sin x$. Now, $|\sin x| \le 1$ for all $x$. Can you finish from here.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine funtion (so as the sine one) is lipschitzian. Indeed, $$|\cos y-\cos x|\le |y-x|,\quad x,y\in\Bbb R.$$ Any lipschitzian function is uniformly continuous.